# Select the 2nd nearest div class in css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Please see the following html

```
<div class="slick-track">
  <div class="marg first slide-active">1</div>
  <div class="marg second">2</div>
  <div class="marg third">3</div>
  <div class="marg fourth">4</div>
  <div class="marg fifth">5</div>
  <div class="marg sixth">6</div>
  <div class="marg seventh">7</div>
</div>
```

Here I want to select slide-active and 2nd marg class after slide-active . How I can select this?

For example:

If `slide-active` is coming with `.first` class , then I have to select `.third`.

If `slide-active`  is coming with `.second` , then I have to select `.fourth`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use sibling selector to select it.

```
.slide-active + .marg + .marg
```

Snippet to highlight the selected one when active.

```css
.slide-active + .marg + .marg {background: #ccf;}
```

```html
<div class="slick-track">
  <div class="marg first slide-active">1</div>
  <div class="marg second">2</div>
  <div class="marg third">3</div>
  <div class="marg fourth">4</div>
  <div class="marg fifth">5</div>
  <div class="marg sixth">6</div>
  <div class="marg seventh">7</div>
</div>
```

When the class is in another one:

```css
.slide-active + .marg + .marg {background: #ccf;}
```

```html
<div class="slick-track">
  <div class="marg first">1</div>
  <div class="marg second slide-active">2</div>
  <div class="marg third">3</div>
  <div class="marg fourth">4</div>
  <div class="marg fifth">5</div>
  <div class="marg sixth">6</div>
  <div class="marg seventh">7</div>
</div>
```

> **Note:** This will not work when you are in the last or last but one slide.

Comment: ... though that's a limitation of the question and not your answer :)

Comment: @BoltClock Yep! `:D`

Comment: brilliant answer .. Thank you .

Comment: sorry friend for delaying accept the answer .

Comment: @abilasher No worries mate! Have a nice day.

Comment: please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49669738/responsive-grid-box-with-image-automatically-resize

Comment: @abilasher Sure...

Comment: i got answer friend . sorry for troubling you

Comment: @abilasher Happy that you have got it man. Enjoy the weekend.